# QlikView Convert 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000 to NULL

Tags: sql, date, time, type-conversion, qlikview

I am trying to convert data from SQL as 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000 to be shown as NULL values in QlikView.

I do the following in the QlikView Load statements -

```
SET NullTimeStamp   = if ($1 = '1753-01-01 00:00:00', null(), $1);
Then use it when LOAD:

LOAD

$(NullTimeStamp(YourDateField1)) AS YOURDATEFIELD1,

$(NullTimeStamp(YourDateField2)) AS YOURDATEFIELD2,

$(NullTimeStamp(YourDateField3)) AS YOURDATEFIELD3
```

However, I have many fields with Time and Dates in my tables so I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ive done something similar in the past. The idea is to generate part of the load script in a variable and then use this variable as part of the next load script

```
DummyData:
Load * Inline [
Something1             , Something2, Something3, Something4, Something5
1753-01-01 00:00:00.000,          2,          3,          4, 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000
];

SET NullTimeStamp   = if ($1 = '1753-01-01 00:00:00', null(), $1);

// Define a temp table
// that holds list of fields that have to be checked with NullTimeStamp
Fields:
Load * Inline [
FieldNames 
Something1
Something2
Something3
Something4
Something5
];

let FieldsConcatenation = '';

// loop through the NullTimeStamp-ed fields
for a = 1 to NoOfRows('Fields')
  let f = FieldValue('FieldNames', a);

  // concatenate each iteration to form part of the RealLoad table script
  let FieldsConcatenation = '$(FieldsConcatenation)' &  '$(NullTimeStamp('  &  '$(f)' & ')) as ' & Upper('$(f)') & ',' & chr(13);

next

// remove the last comma
let FieldsConcatenation = left('$(FieldsConcatenation)', Index('$(FieldsConcatenation)', ',' , -1) -1);

// we dont need this anymore
Drop Table Fields;

// add FieldsConcatenation variable as part of the load script
RealLoad:
Load
  $(FieldsConcatenation),
  'a' as LoadTheRestHere
Resident
  DummyData;

// we dont need this anymore 
Drop Table DummyData;
```

`FieldsConcatenation` variable will have the following content:
[image: variable content]

The original table:
[image: original table]

And the final table:
[image: final table]